# Environment Configuration on Streamlit Cloud

Tags: python, flask, protocol-buffers, tensor, streamlit

pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.tensorflow 2.11.0 requires protobuf<3.20,>=3.9.2,but you have protobuf 3.20.3 which is incompatible.
This is the error i'm getting
I checked the version of protobuf by pip list which came out to be 3.19.6 which streamlit dose not install but by default it takes version 3.20.3 which is incompatible with tensor flow version that i'm using

```
 My requirements.txt
    requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
    rsa==4.9
    scikit-learn==1.2.0
    scipy==1.9.3
    six==1.16.0
    tensorboard==2.11.0
    tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
    tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
    tensorflow==2.11.0
    tensorflow-estimator==2.11.0
    tensorflow-cpu==2.11.0
    tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.29.0
    termcolor==2.1.1
    threadpoolctl==3.1.0
    tomli==2.0.1
    typing_extensions==4.4.0
    urllib3==1.26.13
    Werkzeug==2.2.2
    wincertstore==0.2
    wrapt==1.14.1
    xgboost==1.7.2
    yarg==0.1.9
    zipp==3.11.0
```

Comment: How are you deploying and how are you specifying your environment? Is this Streamlit Cloud by chance? Can you show your complete requirements.txt file?

Comment: Yes this is streamlit cloud and here is my requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

There is a little peculiarity with Streamlit Cloud regarding protobuf. Due to a previous bad build of protobuf, the version got pinned on Streamlit Cloud. See this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/streamlit/docs/issues/639).

Having a requirements.txt file with everything pinned to a single version gives little to no room for pip to resolve anything.

1. Remove any version pins that you don't truly need so pip *can* resolve it
2. Unless needed to pin the version, remove any package that is automatically installed as a dependency to another listed package.
3. Include protobuf in you requirements.txt file with version as noted below

You many need to record it as pinned at the version Streamlit Cloud is forcing it so pip knows this is the case, or you can try telling pip to pin protobuf at a different version and see if works. The particulars on Streamlit Cloud may vary over time. Here is [a dev's response](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/why-is-protobuf-forced-installed-in-version-3-20-1/42150/16?u=mathcatsand) to someone dealing with this issue which is the source of my suggestion here.